# Change css for the current selected li

Tags: css

I have this menu:

```
<div id="menu-home">
    <ul>
        <li> a </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I am on the `test.php` page that corresponds to test menu, I need it's `li` to have a different style..

I tried

```
#menu-home ul li:active
```

but it didn't work..

Thanks

Comment: Add a class to active `li` element.

Comment: You can assign a class or style to the li of the currently active link through jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### There is no `:active` state for `<li>`

Instead you can do it with PHP.

```
<div id="menu-home">
<ul>
<li <?php if (page is current page) echo ' class="active"';?>> a </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And in the CSS, you can give this:

```css
#menu-home ul li.active {}
```

Comment: Seems like I'm typing to slow ;)

Comment: Hey thanks :)
i tried this.. but i get some error..
can you please check it?

echo "<li if (page is current page) echo ' class='active'';><a href='lista.php'>Lista e Porosive</a></li>";

Comment: Dude, seriously? I asked you to write the function! Replace `page is current page`!!!

Comment: Well, i know my question is dumb, but i don't know how to do it!
I mean replace it with what?

Comment: How do you differentiate your pages?

Answer (score 0):

The `<li>` element does not have an active state, since it is just meant to be a (stateless) bullet point. The selector `:active` can only be used on a link; an example can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp).

However, `:active` will only highlight the link as it is clicked. After that, it performs whatever action and/or navigation it is set to do and then the link will be visited. From there on you can't tell it apart from the other already visited pages that you are not currently viewing and it does not become "unvisited" again, even if you navigate to another page. So this does not do what you intend.

Instead, I would create a class `.active` in your CSS where you can define all your custom styling. Then, the PHP that generates your pages needs to take care of setting the class correctly on the selected menu item, ie.: attach `class="active"` it either to the `<li>` or the `<a>` whenever the menu is build.

(yeah, just see Praveen's answer for the code ^^)